# Samba with Windows ACLs, cannot add UNIX groups from Windows

Tags: permissions, windows-10, samba4

I've just got around to setting up Samba on a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS. I managed to get a share accessible from Windows 10 machines on the network. I then enabled Windows ACLs since I wanted a more granular permissions control over directories with many users.

Here comes the issue, when I am viewing a directories permissions from Windows using Context menu> Properties> Security> Edit> Add and I want to add a UNIX group of another UNIX user I cannot since it doesn't exist?

Any directory made in the share has the UNIX user and their group permission principal on the directory but if I were to remove the group principal I would not be able to add it back. BUT I can add any Samba UNIX user to the permissions. Do the groups have to exposed somehow to the Windows clients?

[image]

Here is the smb.conf, it is the default config file with minor changes.

```
[global]
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        logging = file
        map to guest = Bad User
        max log size = 1000
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        server role = standalone server
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        unix password sync = Yes
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        map acl inherit = Yes
        vfs objects = acl_xattr


[printers]
        browseable = No
        comment = All Printers
        create mask = 0700
        path = /var/spool/samba
        printable = Yes


[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[nas]
        comment = NAS
        path = /shares/
        read only = No
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it from the wrong end ;-)
You need to create a group on Windows, lets call it 'win_group' and then create another group on Ubuntu, lets call this one 'unix_group'. You then map, on the Samba server, one to the other with: net groupmap add unixgroup=unix_group ntgroup=win_group
This must be done as 'root'.
You then just use 'win_group' on Windows and Samba will do the rest for you.

Comment: That makes sense. Now when making a Windows group on one machine will that group have to be created on all other Windows machines or is it a one time thing?

Comment: You would have to create the Windows group on all Windows machines, unless you run a domain instead, in which case you would set Samba up differently.